# Could not find org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:4.1

Tags: android, android-webview, adblock

I am trying to use the `AdblockWebView` in my android project. I am using the adblockplus webview so I added the dependecy to my app `build.gradle`.

https://github.com/adblockplus/libadblockplus-android

```css
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:4.1'

    ...
}
```

but I am getting the following error when I build the project, and also when I try to use the `org.adblockplus.libadblockplus.android.webview.AdblockWebView` Android Studio could find the class.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:4.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/adblockplus/adblock-android-webview/4.1/adblock-android-webview-4.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/adblockplus/adblock-android-webview/4.1/adblock-android-webview-4.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I opened the `jcenter` url and it saying 404 not found, is the adblock library removed or what?

https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/org/adblockplus/adblock-android-webview/4.1/adblock-android-webview-4.1.pom?referrer

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
implementation 'org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:4.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:4.3.0'
```

Comment: Please also explain why that answer should help in the given situation.

Comment: @frankenapps version 4.1 has been removed